# Cannot pipe on combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to follow [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/facades-with-rxjs-only) but am running into an issue when using `combineLatest()`:

> `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, Item[], User[]]>'`

**Here is my facade:**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { combineLatest, distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  test: string;
}

export interface Item {
  test: string;
}

interface State {
  items: Item[];
  users: User[];
}

let _state: State = {
  items: [],
  users: [],
};

@Injectable()
export class Facade {
  private store = new BehaviorSubject<State>(_state);
  private state$ = this.store.asObservable();

  items$ = this.state$.pipe(map(state => state.items), distinctUntilChanged());
  emails$ = this.state$.pipe(map(state => state.users), distinctUntilChanged());

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    combineLatest(this.items$, this.emails$).subscribe(
      ([items, users]) => {}
    );
  }
}
```

`items$` and `emails$` are both Observables. This code nearly mirrors the code in the example above, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you're using version 6+ of RxJS, [as per the migration docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#howto-convert-deprecated-methods):

1. `combineLatest` from `rxjs/operators` has been deprecated. You should now import the method directly:

   ```js
   import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
   ```
2. The new version of `combineLatest()` accepts an **array of `Observables`** as its argument:

   ```js
   combineLatest([this.items$, this.emails$]).subscribe(([items, emails]) => {});
   ```